# writing from a form to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following piece of code to make a input form being written in table named "client" database 'smsmart' which has fields name , address and phone

```
<?php

define ('DB_USER', 'root');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define ('DB_NAME', 'smsmart');

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("smsmart");

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . smsmart . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value1 = $_POST['username'];
$value2 = $_POST['address'];
$value3 = $_POST['mobileno'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO client (name,address,phone) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3')";

mysql_close();
?>
```

The fields 'username' 'address' and 'mobileno' from form is not being written into database. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Paste yout HTML form please.

Comment: You're not executing the query

Comment: `$r = mysql_query($sql);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving your query in a variable but that variable isn't doing anything itself

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

**mysql_query** will help you to insert all the data in your Database.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're generating the `$sql` query but not executing it. Given the lack of sanitation on your `$_POST` inputs, you should probably use a parametric or PDO method to protect yourself against potential SQL attacks.

Here is an example of a parameter-based mySQLi insert.

```
// connect to the database
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smsmart");
// prepare statement
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbConnection, "INSERT INTO client (name,address,phone) VALUES (?,?,?)");
// bind parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $value1, $value2, $value3);
// execute statement
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
// close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
// close database connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `mysql_query()`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO client (name,address,phone) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3')";
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO client (name,address,phone) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3')";

mysql_close();
```

hence add **mysql_query**

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO client (name,address,phone) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3')";
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks great except one:
 Just Use mysql_query() function, Like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO client (name,address,phone) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', 
     '$value3')";
     mysql_query($sql);
     mysql_close();
```